# How to get color from the color pallete in selenium webdriver in C#

Tags: selenium

I'm very new to selenium and I'm experiencing an error when I'm going to select a colour from a colour palette.

[image]

When I'm trying to find that web element using XPath system returns an `"Element not found"` exception.

Someone please help me :)

```
    IWebElement BGColorDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[22]/span/span/span[2]/span"));
BGColorDropdown.Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
//Select value form "BG Color dropdown list"
IWebElement BGColorDropdownValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='4f9e73b0-6ffd-465c-bbee-7a8214e76a78']/div[3]/div/div/a"));BGColorDropdownValue.Click();
```

Comment: Share your code as well as target page `URL` or/and `HTML` of *palette*

Comment: IWebElement BGColorDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[22]/span/span/span[2]/span"));
BGColorDropdown.Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
//Select value form "BG Color dropdown list"
IWebElement BGColorDropdownValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='4f9e73b0-6ffd-465c-bbee-7a8214e76a78']/div[3]/div/div/a"));BGColorDropdownValue.Click();

Comment: Please see the code in the original post

Comment: Target Page
https://demo.econz.co.nz:1000/AdminPortal/Account/Login/exptest
User Name : Jiya
PW : Jiya@345
Then go to User Interface -> Buttons-> Add new Record->BG Color

Comment: Check my answer. Mark it as `Accepted` if it solved your problem. Also **do not provide** with your personal credentials (username/password) and other sensitive information both in question or comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attribute that you're trying to use in your `XPath` is dynamic. Try selectors from below code instead:

```
IWebElement BGColorDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Add new record"));
BGColorDropdown.Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
IWebElement BGColorDropdownValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-container-for='BG_COLOR']/following::span[@class='k-icon k-i-arrow-s']"));    
BGColorDropdownValue.Click();
```

Also note that you should use [relative `XPath` instead of absolute](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium) as it's more flexible, reliable and verbose